# Use qmlRegisterType with Q_ENUM and typedef enum

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml

I'd like to use in my QML files an enum coming from another header. After wrapping it with Q_ENUM, I can't make it work with `qmlRegisterType`:

```
class Test: public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

     typedef foo::bar Foobar; // bar is the enum, contained in a namespace foo

     Q_ENUM(Foobar)

     public:
          static void declareQML()
          {
              qmlRegisterType<Foobar>("TestEnums", 1, 0, "Foobar");
          };
}
```

With `MSVC 2013`, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013\include\QtQml\qqml.h:244: error: C2838: 'staticMetaObject' : illegal qualified name in member declaration

see reference to function template instantiation 'int qmlRegisterType<Test::Foobar>(const char *,int,int,const char *)' being compiled
```

Is it because the enum is enclosed in a namespace? Note that I cannot amend the file containing the namespace and the enum (generated by `protobuf`).

Answer (score 2):

`qmlRegisterType()` will register a type for use in QML, but that would be a `QObject` derived type, not an enum. So you actually need to register `Test`, the enum should be handled by the `Q_ENUM` macro.

The enum must be a part of the `QObject` derived class so that the Qt meta system can process it. I don't think it will work for some external enum.

If the enum is in a regular class, you could make it a `Q_GADGET` to make the moc process it, otherwise you could duplicate the original enum in the body of `Test`.

Lastly, the enum name and values **must** begin with a capital letter in order for it to work in QML.